# integration of page in facebook with external site

Tags: php, facebook

I have a public page in facebook, the users can post info in this page of facebook or comment a post . I need to know if it possible that, when a user publish a post or comment in a post of my page in facebook,  i can to send info about that post or comment to my external site. the way of the relationships is from facebook to my external site. My external site is written in php and i am using the php sdk for facebook

Comment: By send do your external site do you mean have an embedded widget where the recent comments are displayed or pipe the contents to a script?

Comment: may be, what i need to know if i can notify from facebook to my site when an user publish a post or write a comment in facebook. i know that the communication is from external site to facebook via API, but what i need is in the other way, from facebook to my external site

Comment: What you are looking for are real-time updates: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2

Comment: yes, i am looking something like that, you have tested this feature of facebook api? if you can comment me about your experience with this feature i stay very thankful